# How do I unhide a hidden asp element via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom

I have an ASP element. It was hidden in the aspx.cs page as such:

```
item.Visible = false;
```

After this is done, based on an event which I use JavaScript, I have to unhide this item.

The problem is that I cannot find this item on the DOM because it's hidden so I can't use `document.getElementByID()`.

My question is, how do I select a hidden ASP control in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to give it a hidden style instead, then it's easy

```
item.Style.Add("display", "none");

//javascript
document.getElementById("id").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: im going to accept your answer because it worked. but why "block" instead of "visible?"

Comment: Display attributes for CSS are things like "none", "block", "inline", and "inline-block",   It's basic CSS man  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

An element with `Visible = false` is never rendered on the page, so you'll never be able to access it in JavaScript.

I would recommend hiding the element with `style="display:none"`, like this:

```
item.Style.Add("display", "none");
```